# ¿Como almacenar las migraciones de laravel en diferentes carpetas?

Tags: laravel

bueno mi consulta es muy de novatos me imagino, como puedo yo hacer para que las migraciones de laravel pueda yo almacenarlas en carpetas diferentes, y poder ejecutarlas?

ejemplo:

- carpeta con bases principales
- carpeta relación de bases existentes

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes almacenarlas en carpetas diferentes, dentro de "migrations", y lanzar comandos que se ajusten a esas ubicaciones, ya que `php artisan migrate` y análogos funcionan sobre el directorio por defecto.

Si, por ejemplo, creas un directorio "Users" en "migrations", para ejecutar las migraciones de su interior:

```
php artisan migrate --path=database/migrations/Users
```

Puedes ver más sobre el tema [aquí](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/run-migrations-that-are-scattered-in-different-folders).